# Change type of member parameter for python type hint

Tags: python, mypy

I have a code like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int) -> None:
        self.a: int = a


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a: float) -> None:
        self.a: float = a
```

The problem is that self.a changes from type *int* in the base class, A, to *float* in class B. mypy gives me this error:

```
typehintancestor.py:8: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "int")
```

(Line 8 is the last line)

Is this a bug in mypy or should I change the implementation of class B?

Comment: I'd say it's a bug in mypy. `B` is free to shadow `a` and override `__init__`, as you have done here. A legitimate error would be if you used `A.__init__(self, a)`, which would attempt to pass your `float` to a function expecting an `int`. (I'm purposefully ignoring what `mypy` does/should do with a call to `super`.)

Comment: Put another way, `B` may inherit `A.__init__`, but it's not using it at all here.

Comment: @chepner I don't think it's a bug, it's considered an error to overload the method signature of a subclass (even the types) since it breaks covariance. That being said, I'm not sure I agree with that conclusion.

Comment: Fair point; if I have a `x: List[a]` object, I should be able to assume `x[0].a` is an `int`, whether `x[0]` is an instance of `A` or a subclass of `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in your code. Suppose it was legal to define your classes that way and we wrote the following program:

```
from typing import List

# class definitions here

def extract_int(items: List[A]) -> List[int]:
    return [item.a for item in items]

my_list: List[A] = [A(1), A(2), B(3.14)]
list_of_ints = extract_int(my_list)
```

We expect the `list_of_ints` variable to contain a just ints, but it'll actually contain a float.

Basically, mypy is enforcing that your code follows the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) here.